# Edit BlackBerry cod file with xvi32

Tags: blackberry

I want to a edit a URL in a .cod file, I used XVI32 to open the file and then replaced the URL with a new URL at the same length.
After the change I made the App isn't working on my device after I reinstalled it.
Is it possible to change the URL without ruin the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a cod file content, then its signature becomes incorrect, and the cod file becomes unusable.

Answering your question: it is not possible.

Comment: Hey, What about decompile the .cod with 'Coddec' is it possible this way?

Comment: I know Coddec, but this tool does not generate source code of your cod file, which can be compiled further. It is only for reverse analysis. And moreover it does not work properly for newer cod files (produced with rapc.exe from SDK 6.0, 7.0). Why do you want to deal with binary cod file? Why don't you make an external xml file with urls and load them from your application? Or it is not your app?