# How to retrieve contents of COD files?

Tags: blackberry

I want the contents of cod files of a running application in blackberry ,so is it possible? if yes then how is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question needs some more details. On one level, a COD file is simply a ZIP file - but it really depends on what you want to do...?

Comment: I know that the cod file contents are in encrypted format but i want that content also and i didn't mean that what you want to do means?

Comment: are you trying to reverse engineer? please add more details to the question

Comment: if there are 5 running application on the device and i want to retrieve contents of that particular cod files of that running application then how it is possible?please post the code.i am asking about is the cod file of any application is accessible to us or not and if it is easily accessible then how it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible to do this with running applications. I think there would be some bad security concerns.

In general, I do not think you will be able to decompile & view the contents of the COD files.

But some people say that a tool called [Coddec](http://drbolsen.wordpress.com/2008/07/14/coddec-released/) works.

(as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040267/383414)

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9962367/383414

Comment: OK it is not possible with running application but is it possible for any application installed on blackberry device?